# What is the maximum numeric value I can use for BITWISE functions in Oracle and PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, bit-manipulation

I want to know, what is the maximum value of parameters we can use in the case of BITAND and BITOR functions?

Oracle.

```
BITAND(expr1, expr2)
BITOR(expr1, expr2)
```

PostgreSQL.

```
expr1 & expr2
expr1 | expr2
```

What are the maximum and minimum values allowed for expr1 and expr2 in both the systems?

Comment: You couldn't find this information in the documentation?

Comment: @GordonLinoff For Oracle, I found a few references but they had different numbers for example  -(2(n-1)) .. ((2(n-1))-1) where n is 128 and on other it say 64bit integers, In the case of Postgres, I couldn't find any limit in docs.

Comment: @davindersingh, for Oracle bitand limit is based on the expr1 and expr2 , which should be integers from 1 to 38 of precision. If you put an integer with 39 digits you got numeric overflow error. I don't think there is a bitor in Oracle, unless in a normal enterprise edition. I use actually my bitor implementation using bitand inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

For Postgres, the two operators `|` and `&` support different data types.

Mainly `smallint`, `integer`, `bigint` and `bit`.

So for "numbers" (integers) the maximum value on each side is [the maximum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) for the bigint type: `9223372036854775807`

For bit strings, [the maximum length](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html) is `2147483647` (which could be interpreted as the number `2^2147483647`)